# Code Returning An Infinite Calculation Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that contains array formulas.

I have found some code on the internet to refresh function (recalculate all the formulas within the arrays.

The problem i have is that it causes an infinite calculation loop.

Can anyone suggest a way to stop the code from entering this infinite loop?

```
Sub RefreshAllFormulas()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CurCell As Object
    Dim lastCellFx As Object

    MousePointer = fmMousePointerHourGlass
    Total = 0

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

        Subtotal = 0

        On Error Resume Next

        Sheets(i).Activate
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select

        For Each CurCell In Selection

            If lastCellFx.Formula <> CurCell.Formula Then
                CurCell.Activate
                mnuRefreshSelection
                Set lastCellFx = CurCell
            End If

        Next CurCell

    Next i

    MousePointer = fmMousePointerDefault

    Sheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Turn off calculations in the beginning and turn them back on when it's done?

Comment: What does `mnuRefreshSelection` do?

Comment: @braX, well it'd be quite odd to turn calculation off while in need of refreshing formula calculation...

Comment: Remember to close your On error resume next. And maybe remove it first to check for errors.

Comment: @DisplayName - turning calculation to manual does not stop a new formula producing a result but it will temporarily halt unnecessary iterative calculation due to dependencies. Once it is turned back on, the worksheet wiil recalc any cell that is 'dirty'.

Comment: i solved the issue by selecting a range and then adding the mnuRefreshSelection code and repeating this for each array